# How to select several specific tabs in a code rather than tab names

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I am creating a VBA code to select 3 specific tabs to convert into PDF. I want to be able to select 3 specific sheets from the list of sheets in "Microsoft Excel Objects" so that even if the order of the sheets is changed or sheets are renamed, the same tabs will be selected and converted into a PDF.

At the moment, I have this code to select the first 3 tabs. (which works fine)

```
 Sheets(Array(1, 2, 3)).Select
```

I have tried the below (doesn't work)

```
Sheets(Array(Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)).Select
```

Expected result is to be able to select 3 specific sheets from the list of sheets in "Microsoft Excel Objects" so that even if the order of the sheets is changed or renamed, the same tabs will be selected and converted into a PDF.

Comment: Place "" around each sheet in your second example; e.g. "Sheet1" If you have specific sheet names the use the name within ""; e,g. "Tom Thumb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the names to do a multi-select.  But you can refer to the codename to get the name: `Sheet1.Name`

```
Sheets(Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet2.Name, Sheet3.Name)).Select
```

You would change the `Sheet1` and others to the CodeName of the sheets you want to select.

Comment: @Louis this is an English-only site means that the language should be **used** in questions and answers is English.

Comment: If I want to expend this code so that beside what this code already does, it extracts sheet3 again but this time separately and save it into the same location as the other PDF document only if A1 cell is not blank. Do I need to submit a new question all together?

Comment: @Abigal new questions get new posts.  Please ask the new question so the community as a whole can help.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to assign a unique `CustomProperty` to each sheet you want to export:

```
Sub qwerty()
    ActiveSheet.CustomProperties.Add Name:="PDF", Value:="pdf1"
End Sub
```

and similar for the other two sheets.

Then when you want to export, loop through all sheets looking for the proper CustomProperty.  It won't matter if the sheet names have been changed or the CodeNames have been changed or the order of sheets has been changed.